# PHP Copy not working after update to php 5.5

Tags: php

I am using php copy function to extract a zip file and put files to a new directory using copy function (actually i am not using $zip->extractTo because it maintains dir stucture of zip as well, and I want to unzip all the files in a single directory that I am creating ).
my code is

```
 $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($src)===true)
    {
        //$zip->extractTo($dest);
        //$zip->close();

        // Above method maintain dir stucture of zip as well, 
        // but we need files directly in dest folder
        for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) 
        {
            $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
            if(substr($filename, -1) == '/')
                continue; // Its a directory name so skip and dont add in dest folder
            $fileinfo = pathinfo($filename);
            copy("zip://".$src."#".$filename, $dest.$fileinfo['basename']);
        }
         $zip->close();
        return true;
    }
```

This is working fine on my development and QA servers where I have PHP 5.2 and 5.3
But it is not working on a PHP 5.5.14.

```
copy("zip://".$src."#".$filename, $dest.$fileinfo['basename']);
```

returns false.
So problem is with copy.

Can anyone please suggest what can be solution.

Comment: Chances are it's a filesystem permission problem or a missing target directory problem, but without a meaningful error message it's hard to say.  Turn on error reporting/logging.

Comment: Have you installed the [`zip extension`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) ?

Comment: zip extension is installed, I am creating a zip file on another place and that is a success.
error reporting and display errors is ON but no error displayed,
Even there is no error in error logs.